# The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute for ACF Docker Image

Tags: docker, coldfusion

We are currently in the process of migrating from windows to ACF 2021 docker images. I'm stuck on getting the dotnet integrations to work.

I have dropped the .dlls required for the dotnet integrations to work (from our old windows instances) in the required directories for the cfobject call to find them. It is able to find the dlls but I receive the error "The assembly that contains the class must be provided to the assembly attribute". I believe this is misleading because the dlls work just find on the windows environment.

My question is whether or not I need extra configuration in the docker images for the local dlls or need to point to dlls on a remote windows server for the .net integration to work.

I have read 
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/using-microsoft-net-assemblies/accessing-net-assemblies.html

But it is still unclear to me.

Any insight is much apperciated.

Comment: You might try asking on the CFML Slack's Docker channel. https://cfml.slack.com/, you can sign up here: https://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/